# iPhone - How do I know if the vibrate is on or off for iOS?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, vibration

Do you know how I may know if the iPhone is on vibrate mode ?
I don't find anything about this on the Web... Too tired to see ?

I want to display an icon in the app so that the user can know looking at it if the phone is on vibrate mode or not. Tha app has also different behaviours depending on if the user wants to be disturbed (vibrate off) or not (vibrate on).

Thank you.

Comment: I know I shouldn't, but... *snicker*

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by knowing it's on vibrate mode?  For audio playback?

Comment: @iWasRobbed : I want to display an icon in the app so that the user can know looking at it if the phone is on vibrate mode or not.

Comment: Not sure that the visual indicator is really necessary. You shouldn't really ever need to know. You simply give commands to the OS and then it responds depending on the hardware state.

Comment: @FreeAsInBeer : May I describe the whole application stuff ? It does not only show an indicator. It has different behaviours depending on the fact that the user want to be disturbed or not.

Comment: So just put an option in your app to act in silent mode.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this using:

```
#import "AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h"

- (void) ifSilentModeThenShowIcon
{
   CFStringRef state;
   UInt32 propertySize = sizeof(CFStringRef);
   AudioSessionInitialize(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
   AudioSessionGetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRoute, &propertySize, &state);

   if(CFStringGetLength(state) == 0)
   { 
     // phone's ringer is off so put
     // some icon showing code here
   }
}
```

[Source](http://iphone-dev-tips.alterplay.com/2009/12/iphone-silent-mode-detection.html)

Comment: Nice find.  I'm assuming this is safe for the App Store?

Comment: Yes, these are just audio session properties so it is public API.  More info here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/AudioSessionServicesReference/Reference/reference.html

Comment: AudioSessionInitialize and AudioSessionGetProperty are deprecated in iOS 7, is there another way to do this?