# how to determine phone's profile (vibrate/ringing) using phonegap?

Tags: cordova

I am developing an application using phonegap.
I want to put a notification feature like beep/vibrate.
but how can I determine whether the phone is in vibrate mode or in ringing mode ??
**Note: I must use phonegap api only.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this in native and add it as a plugin to PhoneGap.This how you do it in native :[iPhone - How do I know if the vibrate is on or off for iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519807/iphone-how-do-i-know-if-the-vibrate-is-on-or-off-for-ios)