# Detect mute (silent mode) in IOS6

Tags: ios6, detect, mute

I know that Apple does not provide a way to detect the state of the iPhone mute/silence switch in iOS 6. In fact, I only want to detect the state of the iPhone which is mute or not now. Does anyone have some method to detect it? Many thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone - How do I know if the vibrate is on or off for iOS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519807/iphone-how-do-i-know-if-the-vibrate-is-on-or-off-for-ios)